# errors while running hive queries

Tags: hive

I am trying to run hive queries but I am getting errors as:

```
hive> FROM (                                                   
    > FROM t1
    > MAP t1.patient_mrn, t1.encounter_date
    > USING 'retrieve'
    > AS mp1, mp2
    > CLUSTER BY mp1) map_output
    >   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t3
    > REDUCE map_output.mp1, map_output.mp2
    > USING 'q1.txt'
    > AS reducef1, reducef2;
```

Total MapReduce jobs = 1

Launching Job 1 out of 1

Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1

In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=

In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=

In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=

Starting Job = job_201112281627_0097, Tracking URL = http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201112281627_0097

Kill Command = /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2//bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:54311 -kill job_201112281627_0097

2011-12-31 03:10:46,391 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%

2011-12-31 03:11:29,794 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%

Ended Job = job_201112281627_0097 with errors
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
hive>

Answer (score 2):

Best advice without knowing a lot more is where to find the error logs. So go to your JobTracker's web page, find the page for that job, and drill down to find the error logs. 
Look for any "failed" tasks, click there to get to the page for that specific task. 
You'll eventually get to the page containing the task-specific log, and that should help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen in n number of scenarios. Rerun the query once more and check the jobtracker for the failed/killed attempts and go through the logs for exact reason.